# How to set active property on js menu object?

Tags: javascript

I create a menu navigation to my website, this menu is simple and built by my object:

```
const routes = [
  {
    text: "im foo",
    path: "foo",
    active: null,
    children: [
      {
        text: "im foo",
        path: "baz",
        active: null,
        children: [
          {
            text: "im foo",
            path: "baz",
            active: null,
            children: [{ text: "im foo", path: "daz", active: null }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "im A",
    path: "a",
    active: null,
    children: [
      {
        text: "im B",
        path: "b",
        active: null,
        children: [
          {
            text: "im c",
            path: "c",
            active: null
          },
          {
            text: "im d",
            path: "d",
            active: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This menu is have collapse behavior. that mean I can open and close items in the menu **like** this:

[image]

And when the `active` property set to true I give a class that make the menu open.

My Question is how to set the `active` property by given url? for example my url is `foo/bar/baz/daz`, so I need to find where is `daz` and go up.

The problem is how I do the "go up"? I'm not sure how to implement this thing.

Comment: loop through find first part foo and set active; then loop through its children find and set true and so on if it does not exist show error? What is issue what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to loop through the routes array and find the active node and then add class to it? Here is the code for find the node. Hope that help.

```
findNode(nodes: Array<any>) {
        let nodesArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nodes));
        nodesArray.forEach(rootNode => {
            let queue = [];
            queue.push(rootNode);

            while (queue.length > 0) {
                let nodeObj = queue.shift();
                
                // TODO: this is the place for your logic to find the node
                
                if (nodeObj && nodeObj.children) {
                    nodeObj.children.forEach(element => {
                        queue.push(element);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const routes = [
  {
    text: "im foo",
    path: "foo",
    active: null,
    children: [
      {
        text: "im foo",
        path: "baz",
        active: null,
        children: [
          {
            text: "im foo",
            path: "baz",
            active: null,
            children: [{ text: "im foo", path: "daz", active: null }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "im A",
    path: "a",
    active: null,
    children: [
      {
        text: "im B",
        path: "b",
        active: null,
        children: [
          {
            text: "im c",
            path: "c",
            active: null
          },
          {
            text: "im d",
            path: "d",
            active: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];


function setActive(routes, paths) {
  if (paths.length === 0) return true; // match all
  if (!routes) return false; // not match all
  const path = paths.shift();
  const matchRoute = routes.find(i => i.path === path);
  if (matchRoute) {
    const preState = matchRoute.active;
    const isMatchAll = setActive(matchRoute.children, paths);
    matchRoute.active = isMatchAll || preState;
    return isMatchAll;
  }
  // no route found
  return false;
}

// ok,  mark the path with active true
setActive(routes, "foo/baz/baz/daz".split("/"));

// No match, leave it as it is
// setActive(routes, "foo/baz/baz/dz".split("/"));
console.log(routes);
```

Comment: thank you but I want to mark the path with active true, if it found, not just the root.

Comment: I now see what you mean and can use the backtracking algorithm to solve this problem.